# How to bind subproperties of Objetcts in JavaFX

Tags: java, binding, javafx

I know following code won't compile. But this is exactly what I want:

```
 public ObjectProperty<File> myFile = new SimpleObjectProperty<File>();
 Label fileName = new Label();
 fileName.textProperty().bind(myFile.getValue().getName());
```

Being able to bind properties of an object like java.util.File without declaring every property of File as e.g. StringProperty. How should I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaFX 8, you can use the [`Bindings`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html) API to do this:

```
fileName.textProperty().bind(Bindings.selectString(myFile, "name"));
```

You can also consider using the [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind) framework, with

```
fileName.textProperty().bind(EasyBind.map(myFile, File::getName));
```

Comment: Correct answer. But what about vice versa binding? Binding a TextField textProperty to a POJO property to store inputs in that POJO property?

Comment: You can't do that with a binding (it's ambiguous as to how to set the POJO property). You need to use a listener and update the property manually.

Comment: Why it is ambiguous if the POJO follows JavaBean style? Properties are getting setters and with a syntax for selectString, this should be possible. Other EL using the same concept for binding POJOs through expression binding (JSF for example).

Comment: In general (though not in this case) there are two values that could be changed in order to achieve what you want: the `File` object could be changed to a new `File` with the specified name, or the name of the current `File` object could be changed.